# Tycho include bundle into another one

Tags: java, maven, tycho

I have the following two bundles:

```
Master:
  - lib/
  - META-INT/MANIFEST.MF
  - plugin.xml
  - build.properties

Dependency:
  - src/some_package/
  - META-INT/MANIFEST.MF
  - build.properties
```

And I would like to end-up with the following jar structure using Maven-tycho:

```
Master.jar:
  - lib/Dependency.jar:
    - some_package/
    - META-INT/MANIFEST.MF
    - build.properties
  - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  - plugin.xml
  - build.properties
```

Any idea how I could do this? I guess I'll have to use the assembly plugin but  I'm struggling with the Maven part...

Thx!

EDIT: I'm currently trying with this pom.xml on Master

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2011, EclipseSource and others All rights reserved. This 
    program and the accompanying materials are made available under the terms 
    of the Eclipse Public License v1.0 which accompanies this distribution, and 
    is available at http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html -->

<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugins</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Master</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
    <version>0.0.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-dependency-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependency</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <item>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>Dependency</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                </item>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your current pom? Besides the assembly plugin, you might look into the maven shade plugin

Comment: @asettouf I've updated my post with the current POM that do not do what I expect. I'll have a look at this plugin thx!

Comment: The problem is here the dependency plugin is not made to include dependencies in the jar. You either need the assembly plugin or perhaps the shade plugin

Comment: @asettouf this was a try... actually if I call this into the "verify" phase, it copies it at the right location but AFTER the Master jar has been created :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with the following POM only if "Dependency" is included into the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of "Master".

Note the **compile** phase.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2011, EclipseSource and others All rights reserved. This 
    program and the accompanying materials are made available under the terms 
    of the Eclipse Public License v1.0 which accompanies this distribution, and 
    is available at http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html -->

<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugins</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Master</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
    <version>0.0.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-dependency-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependency</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <item>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>Dependency</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                </item>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```